# React Js Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React. It's working fine on server after build even it work fine when I go to the another page, but when I refresh on another page it show me not found.

[image]

Comment: The basic gist is that the server needs to serve the root index.html file for any page request into your app. Where/how are you deploying/serving the React app from? See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to gather to general sense what configurations different server environments may need. Please [edit] your post to include more details, possibly including a [mcve].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587) Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

if you deploy in netlify, you can do this:

1. in /public, add file _redirects
2. inside _redirects file, you can write this line /* /index.html 200

second way :

1. in the App.jsx/js change BrowserRouter to HashRouter, but this way will be generate your page like example.netlify.app/#/yourpage.

there is a hash in your url.